# Delete Ghost images uploaded on AWS S3

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, ghost

I'm building a Ghost application and it will be hosted on Heroku that can not store image uploads so what I did is to search around on Google and I found a way to upload images directly to Amazon buckets.

After a 4 hours fight I've been able to upload and read images from the S3 to the Ghost blog but what I wish also to achieve is to delete an image I'm not using anymore.

Let's say I upload an image, I don't like it and I replace it with another. The S3 keep both images.

There is a way to delete both images from Ghost and S3?

I'm using ghost-s3-storage. Thanks

Comment: When you store the images to S3, do you assign a unique key or randomly generate one? S3 should replace the original image for the key you provided, when you replace.

Comment: I don't know about this key... I just followed a guide and "keys" are not explained... I spent 3 hours to assign the right policy to the IAM and maybe I missed something... I never did something like that before